# Can view be called directly from reactjs in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using ReactJS to call WebAPI. I would like to make the application standalone, would be deploying WebAPI service on a server and ReactJS code in another.

Now my question here is -
1. Is it possible to call a view directly from ReactJS, eliminating the need to call controllers?

Comment: Capitalization and made sentence flow more smoothly.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a view directly from ReactJS"? Are you trying to do server-side rendering or create a static application with a separate Web API?